# ASPX Как вывести на страницу только текст?

Tags: c#, aspx

Вывожу данные на страницу *name.aspx*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>
...
<id><input type="text" id="ID" runat="server" /></id>
...
```

В коде получаю:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
...
<id><input name="ID" type="text" id="ID" value="**12345**" /></id>
...
```

Таким образом, на странице присутствует лишний код (HTML разметка):

```
<input name="ID" type="text" id="ID" value="..." />
```

А должно получиться:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
...
<id>**12345**</id>
...
```

Как вывести данные таким образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен `asp:Literal`:

```
<id><asp:Literal ID="literal1" runat="server" Text="**12345**" /></id>
```

он не добавляет лишней разметки.

Если значение лежит, например, в свойстве страницы, то можно вставить его и без контролов:

```
<id><%= this.SomeNonStaticProperty %></id>
```

или

```
<id><%= SomeClass.SomeStaticProperty %></id>
```

`<%= ... %>` - это шорткат к `Response.Write`, все что написано между скобками - будет выполнено и записано прямо в ответ, между вашими тегами `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label` - *Represents a label control, which displays text on a Web page*.

Comment: Label тоже оставляет разметку:
`<span id="Label1">**12345**</span>`

Comment: Если вам не нужна разметка то вы сами должны рендерить страницу protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output) {
    if ( (HasControls()) && (Controls[0] is LiteralControl) ) {
        output.Write("<H2>Your Message: " + ((LiteralControl) Controls[0]).Text + "</H2>");
    }
}